# How to create a random function that returns a different value every time?

Tags: c#, random, while-loop

I am trying to write a Random function that returns a random number, which is different than the 5 last different numbers it returned.

A very simular code that I use in excel VBA:

```vb
    Function Rand(ByVal Low As Long, ByVal High As Long) As Long
Randomize
    Num3 = Num2
    Num2 = Num1
  Rand = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd) + Low
  Num1 = Rand

 Do While Num1 = Num2 Or Num1 = Num3 Or Sheets(Csheet).Cells(Num1, 3) > 20

      Rand = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd) + Low
     Num1 = Rand
  Loop
End Function
```

The number also needs to check that the word at heb[i].Known is false.
I tried this one:

```
private int Rand(int Min, int Max)
        {
            int i;
            int x = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            oldNum[3] = oldNum[2];
            oldNum[2] = oldNum[1];
            oldNum[1] = oldNum[0];
            do
            {

                i = rnd.Next(Min, Max);
                x++;
            }
            while (Heb[i].Known==false && x<10000 && oldNum.Contains(i));
            oldNum[0] = i;
            return i;

        }
```

Nevertheless it doesen't seem to cooperate too well... it returns 0 every time.

Min and Max is the Range in the list it randomises from (should be between 1 -30)
Heb is the number of items in the list (about 500 - 1000 items)
I initialize oldNum with:

```
  int[] oldNum = new int[3];
```

Comment: what's wrong with the Random() class?

Comment: What does it do that you didn't expect?

Comment: Ehm, if each number must be different from the previous five, it's not as random as it should be! Anyway, your example seeds the randomiser every time you need a new random number, and that doesn't work well. Make the `rnd` static and call the `Random` function only once.

Comment: It returns 0 every time.

Comment: What is `Min`, what is `Max`, how large is `Heb`, are there any true `Known` values in `Heb`, what do you initialise `oldNum` with, etc.

Comment: The initial problem is almost plausible, but the `Heb[i]` condition makes me think you're using the wrong tool for the job here. And `x<10000` isn't going to save you when `Max-Min < 5`.

Comment: By the way - I would like to know - why did my question recieve the harsh -4 score?? is it that bad and stupid? how should I ask something like this in the future?

Comment: "Why the -4" - don't know, it's not all that bad. Wrong time of the day/week to ask I suppose.

Comment: As an aside *"not the previous five return values"* makes the output *less* random than a plain ol', high quality PRNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a `Queue`!

```
Random rng = new Random();
Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();

private int Rand(int min, int max)
{
    int r;

    while(queue.Contains(r = rng.Next(min, max)));

    queue.Enqueue(r);

    if(queue.Count > 5) queue.Dequeue();

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Or a simple fixed array with a roll-over index.